# At what depth does the ground stop getting cooler/hotter(summer/winter) and it starts to warm up?Where is the MAT depth or geothermal crossover?

Tags: geology, temperature, geothermal-heat, underground-water

Lookin into geothermal cooling, and want to learn more about how temperature behaves at different depths, not too deep like 100 meters or so, ignoring unusual stuff like geysers and things.
I want to know at what depth does it stabilize to the MAT(mean annual temp) and how much does it generally increase every few meters from there. Also what should i search for to find a graph that displays this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Earth Science Stack Exchange!  Did you read https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/14397/6 and the answers there?

Comment: Yes i did, it popped up when i was writing this but i didn't find it very precise in regards to the depth it starts to get warmer, i was hoping to get pointed in the direction of a graph or a scientific study with one. I live in Mendoza argentina and the mean average temp is 16-17C but my friend has a well that has 18C water, i was wondering if it's being warmed up a bit because it's 90m underground.

Comment: The depth at which the ground starts to get warmer will vary with geology for each region. Additionally, some locations will have "hot" spots due to geothermal activity, such as hot springs, or higher concentrations of radioactive elements.

Comment: I know you are trying to help but you do realize that tells me nothing, also i said "ignoring unusual stuff like geysers and things"